# Raspberry / SIM900A module calling problem

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

I am trying to call my phone from raspberry pi through SIM900A module ,
I interface the wires well and the module blinking .
the python code run and say that its calling, but my phone don't ringing ?
this is the code

````
import os, time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

port.write(b'AT\r')

rcv = port.read(10)

print(rcv)

time.sleep(1)

port.write(b'ATDxxxxxxxxxx')

print('Calling…')

time.sleep(30)

port.write(b'ATH\r')

print('Hang Call…')```


The output is :
 

b'T\r\r\nok\r\n'
calling...
Hang call...

The mincom give me a response OK for AT command
````

Comment: Have you tried doing this manually in a serial comm app (eg. `minicom` or `miniterm.py`)?  You will probably get better feedback about what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't finish your ATD command with carriage return (`\r`) character.

It's always good practice to read answers that modem sends back to you. By ignoring them, you don't really know what your problem is, you only know that there is some.